# How to find two words patterns knowing only the first one in r

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset with news articles scraped from the web.

For every article, I would like to write a code that individuates the source, so that I can add it to the dataframe in a separate column.

The problem is that I cannot write a command line that works, I have tried to use grep but I think I am not writing the correct regex.

**Example:**

```
title   content

Art 1   This is article one. Source: The Guardian.  
Art 2   This is    article two. Source: New York Times.   
Art 3   This is article three.    Source: The Washington Post.
```

**Expected result:**

```
title  source  
Art 1  The Guardian  
Art 2  New York Times   
Art 3  Washington Post
```

Here is what I tried (the pattern is always constituted by the word Source followed by : followed by one to three words and finishes with a full-stop):

```
source <- grep("(Source:)([:alpha:]{*})(.\)", df, perl = TRUE)
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
Error in grep("(Source:)([:alpha:]{*})(.))", df, perl = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '(Source:)([:alpha:]{*})(.))'
In addition: Warning message:
In grep("(Source:)([:alpha:]{*})(.))", df, perl = TRUE) :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
    'POSIX named classes are supported only within a class'
    at '[:alpha:]{*})(.))'
```

I have only limited experience with regex and I cannot find anywhere how to accomplish what I have in mind.

Comment: Try `df$source <- regmatches(df$title, regexpr("Source:\\s*\\K.+\\b", df$title, perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to get some substrings from character vectors. `grep` can be used to get whole matching character vectors, so you can't use `grep`.

You may use `regmatches` with `regexpr` to get the substrings. Assuming you have

```
content <- "Art 1 This is article one. Source: The Guardian."
df <- data.frame(content)
```

you may extract the *`source`* column using

```
df$source <- regmatches(df$content, regexpr("Source:\\s*\\K.+\\b", df$content, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [R demo](https://tio.run/##TYyxCsIwFEX3fsUjODRaA66iQwdxcNO6ZXmmrzbQpuUlBf8@JtJBuNO95x6O0UwukAtw2oOoOcABmt56SEEO1gwEkyMFj2lhQ8c0ElwX5NaiU6Jou3xsMaDqGEcqV51My8b/Phlgeo8YTE@@TP3KVLmmz8ylWO1a@63WN7XT@iUq@Edn4uHc3J8XKYvkjvEL)

**Regex details**

- `Source:` - matches a literal text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `.+` - any 0 or more characters other than line break characters, as many as possible up to the last...
- `\b` - word boundary (this will "truncate" the trailing punctuation from the match).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0lcMwb/1).

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_extract` and positive lookbehind ("If you see on the left..."):

```
content <- "This is article one. Source: The Guardian."

library(stringr)
source <- str_extract(content, "(?<=Source: )[^.]*")
[1] "The Guardian"
```

Alternatively, use `sub` and backreference:

```
source <- sub(".*Source: (.*)\\.$", "\\1", content)
[1] "The Guardian"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that did not work well with my dataset because I have a lot of different sources to lookup and I did not know all of them in advance, but it could be a good solution in other cases!